# Selenium IDE how to call js functions in latest version

Tags: selenium-ide

i wrote some javascript, does IDE support this luhnSum += product; as seemed to overwite the object instead of concatendated it . Is there a way in Selenium IDE (the latest version) to call a js file and get the result of this rather than having to do this step by step in Selenium IDE maybe via extensions>

```
Function generateAlpha() {
    var alphaInt = generateRandomNumber(1,26);
    var alphaChar = String.fromCharCode( "A".charCodeAt(0) + alphaInt - 1 );
    var alphaDigits = addPadding(alphaInt.toString(), 2); 
    var random8Int = generateRandomNumber(1, 99999999);
    var random8 = addPadding(random8Int.toString(), 8); 
    var luhnBase = alphaDigits + random8;
    // calculate check digit
    var multipliers = [1,2,1, 2,1,2, 1,2,1, 2];
    var luhnSum = 0;
    for( var x=0; x<10; x++ ) {
    var product = multipliers[x] * parseInt(luhnBase.charAt(x), 10);
        if( product < 10 ) {
            luhnSum += product;
        } else {
            luhnSum += (product-10)+1;
        }
    } 
    var checkDigit = luhnSum % 10; 
    return alphaChar + random8 + checkDigit.toString();
}
```